# How to check if a subplot is empty in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm creating several subplots in matplotlib as:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(100, 85))
axes = axes.flatten()
'Other code for populating the subplots'
```

I want to remove the last plot, if it's empty. I tried this code:

```
if axes[-1] is None:
    axes[-1].set_visible(False)
```

The problem is that the axes elements are object of type `AxesSubplot`:

```
print(axes.flat[-1])

AxesSubplot(0.547727,0.125;0.352273x0.343182)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
if not axes[-1].lines: axes[-1].set_visible(False)
```